# Wifi adapter not found, RTL8821CE after installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, drivers, wireless, hp

I have a HP laptop 15-da2xxx which came with the Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Adapter and pre installed with windows, I made a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS but the Wifi adapter cannot be found.
Running `lspci | grep Network` gives me:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE
802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

I understand there's many duplicates to this question but I've exhausted and tried every solution I could find to no avail.

I followed this guide https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/realtek.html#ID6

Also tried:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall git dkms build-essential
linux-headers-$(uname -r) git clone
https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce cd rtl8821ce chmod +x
dkms-install.sh chmod +x dkms-remove.sh sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

And made sure Secure boot is disabled (Note: in the BIOS it was disabled by default and is grayed out, so I can't enable it either for some reasons)

So I ran the following command to make sure Secure Boot is disabled:

```
sudo apt-get install mokutil && mokutil --sb-state 

mokutil is already the newest version (0.3.0+1538710437.fb6250f-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 138 not upgraded.
SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode
```

EDIT:

```
sudo dkms status

rtl8821ce, v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.8.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
rtl8821ce, v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.8.0-50-generic, x86_64: installed

sudo modprobe 8821 && sudo dmesg | grep -e RTL -e 8821

RTL -e 8821
modprobe: FATAL: Module 8821 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.8.0-50-generic
```

EDIT:

```
sudo modprobe 8821ce && sudo dmesg | grep -e RTL -e 8821
[    0.676010] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: RTL8168h/8111h, 6c:02:e0:d1:5d:91, XID 541, IRQ 127
[ 5291.537145] 8821ce: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[ 5291.537669] 8821ce: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[ 5291.540446] rtl8821ce 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[ 5291.576046] rtl8821ce 0000:03:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `sudo dkms status` and also: `sudo modprobe 8821 && sudo dmesg | grep -e RTL -e 8821`

Comment: @chili555 Edited

Comment: Oops! Sorry for my misstep! It should be: `sudo modprobe 8821ce && sudo dmesg | grep -e RTL -e 8821` Please excuse me and try again.

Comment: @chili555 it's ok tnx for your help, edited again

Comment: Looks like it's working to me. Does it see networks? `nmcli device wifi list` Don't show us the whole output; just tell us if it sees your network. Is the wireless switch or key combination set to enable wireless? `rfkill list all` Does it try to connect? Fail? Drop? Or what?

Comment: @chili555 after countless of shutdowns and restarts it somehow magically worked, not sure what you did but.. thank you!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.